# Get number of executed actions on Logic App workflow run

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Is there a way to programatically (from a REST API) get the number of executed actions per workflow run?
I didn't find anything in the documentation, but when I check out Metrics there's a "Actions succeeded" option.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by linking application insights/Log Analytics to your Logic app. Simply add Diagnostic settings to Send Logs and Metric to Analytics.

See the detailed instructions [here](https://www.serverlessnotes.com/docs/azure-logic-apps-insights-using-log-analytics).

Comment: That's a good solution, however I need to get the data programatically. I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: ok, in that case, you can try to query Log analytics. The data you need should be there since it's presented as chart. You can also execute these queries as Http request. Here is an [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/query) of an Http request.